# can i add a static folder wtih files in the static folder and load files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I want to store a admin folder with different static files in static folder in a django project. Basically, i want to load my user part fronted with some of static files and want to load my admin panel with other diffrent static files. how can i do that?

i add a folder named admin which contains admins static files.
here the snippet
[image]

how can i load user static files and admins static files from admin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Django collects together all static files into 1 folder, defined by [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_ROOT), when you run `manage.py collectstatic`. When this command runs, it will go through each installed app and look for a `static` directory and pull the files into `STATIC_ROOT`.

It's then up to you really, because the template files define the static files they load. Therefore if you want a particular page/view to load it's static files from somewhere else, you just override the template and load the static files as you see fit.